# How to define an enum in Breeze

Tags: breeze

In Mongoose my enum is is defined like this:

```
personType: {
    type:String,
    enum: ['Contact','Donor','Resident'],
},
```

Is there a simple way to make a similar definition in the Breeze metadata?

Comment: I don't believe that Breeze "supports" enums. Not even sure what "support" means. Please explain what you would like to see Breeze do and how it would help you. What would you do if Breeze didn't support enums and how costly is that?

Comment: I would like to be able to define an enum for validation and possibly drop down population. An enum would seem like a fairly basic feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an `enum` in a class library:

```
public enum PersonType
    {
        Contact = 0,
        Donor = 1,
        Resident= 2
    }
```

Then, In the conroller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object Lookups()
    {
   // Some lookup data go here
   var PersonType = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PersonType)); 
   return new {
   // Some lookup objects
   PersonType }
   }
```

Hence, you can get the `PersonType`  as an object along with the lookups from the client side.